# JavaScript engine to enable scripting support / application automation

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I am planning to switch to **JavaScript** as a scripting language for our application, currently we are using VBScript with ***Microsoft VB Script engine***. Scripting scope is being used for Application Automation via exposed APIs and scripts execution can be on-demand, time-based, conditional or event-based.
To enable **JavaScript** support for my application I have shortlisted ***Google V8*** engine, however someone has suggested to use ***Node.js*** instead of ***Google V8***. As everyone knows ***Node.js*** is also backed by ***Google V8*** and primary purpose of Node.js is to create network applications.
As per above context which one of above choices (***Google V8*** or ***Node.js***) will be the best choice. 
Selection parameters are:

1. Implementation
2. Integration
3. Framework Complexity
4. Performance
5. Maintenance

Comment: I have no idea why this is closed as opinion based, it's clearly not opinion based - there is an _obvious objective_ answer.

Comment: I totally agree with Benjamin Gruenbaum, the question clearly asks for comparison on  the basis of valid parameters and constraints e.g. integration cost, framework complexity, performance and maintenance. Can reviewers provide a valid reason which makes this question "opinion based"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoever told you to use node.js does not understand your use case.

If you want to embed a script engine - you can embed V8. Node JS is a whole platform that brings V8 *together with a library* for asynchronous io called libuv, and other tools and libraries dedicated to making networking and server building easy.

It's not nearly as easy to embed as V8 itself and it's not as fun. The performance would likely be very similar and maintenance would be a lot harder with node.